# Windows App Cert Kit: InstallLocation False Failure

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wack

I built an MSI using the WIX Toolset. In the MSI I use:

`<SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" After="CostFinalize"/>`

to set the InstallLocation regkey. When testing with the App Cert Kit I get the failure:

`A non-optional value 'InstallLocation' is missing or invalid for program`.

After checking the registry on my PC and another's the correct registry key

`InstallLocation: C:\Program Files\*program_name*\`

is present on both in the correct location

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{GUID}`.

I tried consulting a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182856/windows-app-certification-kit-test-result-app-didnt-create-the-require-regist) but honestly have no idea what the solution is saying. I also tried running the Cert Kit on the other computer but to no avail. Is this a known bug in the Cert Kit or is that not a valid InstallLocation?

Comment: Same bug with vs installer wizard